# vba - Не выделяются цветом регионы в WebBrowser

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, yandex-maps-api, vba, webbrowser

Пишу макрос, который выделяет области нужного цвета - иным словом, в коде генерирует страничку html с закрашенными областями.

Этот код работает в Chrome и IE9, но не работает в компоненте WebBrowser в Excel:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0023)http://www.contoso.com/ -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>Direction Yandex map.</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/1.1/index.xml?modules=regions" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">
        YMaps.jQuery(function () {
            var map = new YMaps.Map(YMaps.jQuery("#YMapsID")[0]);
            map.setCenter(new YMaps.GeoPoint(108, 62), 3);
            var zoom = new YMaps.Zoom();map.addControl(zoom);map.enableScrollZoom(true);
            YMaps.Regions.load("ru", function (state, response) {
                if (state == YMaps.State.SUCCESS) {
                     var shapes, polygon;
                     var regionVba1 = response.filter(function (obj) {
                         var names = [
                            "Алтайский край", "Астраханская Область", "Волгоградская Область"
                        ];
                        return (names.indexOf(obj.name) > -1);
                    });
                    for (var i = 0; i < regionVba1.length; i++) {
                        shapes = regionVba1[i].metaDataProperty.encodedShapes;
                        for (var ix = shapes.length; ix--; ) {
                            polygon = YMaps.Polygon.fromEncodedPoints(
                                shapes[ix].coords,
                                shapes [ix].levels
                            );
                            polygon.setStyle({
                                polygonStyle: {
                                    fillColor: "b00c0c55",
                                    strokeColor: "b00c0c"
                                }
                            }); 
                            map.addOverlay(polygon);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    alert ("Error: " + response.Error.Message)
                } });
        })
    </script></head>
<body><div id="YMapsID" style="width:920px;height:390px"></div></body>
</html>
```

Как выглядит в Хроме и ИE9:
[image: Chrome и IE9]

Так выглядит в Excel:
[image: Excel]

Как можно подправить код, чтобы он начал работать в WebBrowser'e? К сожалению, в js не силен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому-нибудь это будет полезно.

Погуглив по данной проблеме и с помощью метода тыка выяснилось, что в WebBrowser компоненте стоит версия IE до 9-й, а на старых версиях IE (и в старых версиях Opera) не реализована Array.indexOf(), поэтому в данном случае можно просто добавить в файл этот кусок кода (в js совершенно не силен и с ним сталкиваюсь в который раз, так что возможно это деревянный костыль):

```
    (function(A) {
        A.indexOf = A.indexOf || function(object) {
            for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
                if (i in this && this[i] === object) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        };
    })(Array.prototype);
```

Нашел [тут](http://alljs.ru/articles/array/indexof), да и тема, оказывается, неоднократно мусолилась на [англ stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-internet-explorer-browsers/8813472#8813472).